# Jquery - two select, option - count between and disable

Tags: jquery

I need advice. I have some number of rooms eg 2 or more.
Standard for one person and "single"
Standard for two people and with "double"
It is still the same room. This means that if I select 1x single, the 2x double option will be disabled and the available 1x option will remain and vice versa.

Now I can only block the entire select. I only need to block options.

```js
var x = 2;
$("#frm-step1-standard1").change(function() {
  var va = $(this).val();
  if (va >= x) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard12").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $("#frm-step1-standard12").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Typ</th>
      <th scope="col">Night</th>
      <th scope="col">Price 1 room</th>
      <th scope="col">Number of rooms</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>5 €</td>
      <td>

        <select name="standard1" id="frm-step1-standard1">
          <option style="color: red;" value="0">0</option>
          <option style="color: red;" value="1">1</option>
          <option style="color: red;" value="2">2</option>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0 €</td>
      <td>

        <select name="standard12" id="frm-step1-standard12">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope it's your answer:

```js
   var x = 2;
$("#frm-step1-standard1").change(function() {
  var va1 = $(this).val();
  var va2 = $("#frm-step1-standard12").val();
  if (va1+va2 >= x) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=2]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=2]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});

 $("#frm-step1-standard12").change(function() {
  var va1 = $(this).val();
  var va2 = $("#frm-step1-standard1").val();
  if (va1 + va2 >= x) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=2]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=2]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Typ</th>
      <th scope="col">Night</th>
      <th scope="col">Price 1 room</th>
      <th scope="col">Number of rooms</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>5 €</td>
      <td>

        <select name="standard1" id="frm-step1-standard1">
          <option style="color: red;" value="0">0</option>
          <option style="color: red;" value="1">1</option>
          <option style="color: red;" value="2">2</option>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0 €</td>
      <td>

        <select name="standard12" id="frm-step1-standard12">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it yet. The sum of select one and two values can be max 2. I select one = 1, then select two can be max 1
Select one + select two = 2

Comment: @aha009 check again!

Comment: There is still a mistake. When I select select one = 2, then I can select select two = 1. The sum should be max 2.

Comment: try with :  var x = 1;

Answer (score 0):

I have expanded the solution from [@foadabd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11222433/foadabd)

Is there a more elegant solution? I need it to be dynamic.
var x can be any number.

It still doesn't work properly.

```js
var x = 2;
$("#frm-step1-standard1").change(function() {
  var va1 = parseInt($(this).val());
  var va2 = parseInt($("#frm-step1-standard12").val());
  if (va1 + va2 >= x) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=1]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=2]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (va1 + va2 == 1) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (va1 + va2 == 0) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard12>option[value=2]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});

$("#frm-step1-standard12").change(function() {
  var va1x = parseInt($(this).val());
  var va2x = parseInt($("#frm-step1-standard1").val());
  if (va1x + va2x >= x) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=1]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=2]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (va1x + va2x == 1) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else if (va1x + va2x == 0) {
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=1]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#frm-step1-standard1>option[value=2]").removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Typ</th>
      <th scope="col">Night</th>
      <th scope="col">Price 1 room</th>
      <th scope="col">Number of rooms</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>5 €</td>
      <td>

        <select name="standard1" id="frm-step1-standard1">
          <option style="color: red;" value="0">0</option>
          <option style="color: red;" value="1">1</option>
          <option style="color: red;" value="2">2</option>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0 €</td>
      <td>

        <select name="standard12" id="frm-step1-standard12">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reduced the code so you don't need to have multiple change statements for the dropdowns.

**Demo**

```js
var x = 2;
var selector = $("#frm-step1-standard1,#frm-step1-standard12");
selector.change(function() {
  var va1 = $(this).val();
  var va2 = selector.not(this).val();
  if (va1 + va2 >= x) {
    $("option[value=2]", selector.not(this)).hide()
  } else {
    $("option[value=2]", selector.not(this)).show()
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Typ</th>
      <th scope="col">Night</th>
      <th scope="col">Price 1 room</th>
      <th scope="col">Number of rooms</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>5 €</td>
      <td>

        <select name="standard1" id="frm-step1-standard1">
          <option style="color: red;" value="0">0</option>
          <option style="color: red;" value="1">1</option>
          <option style="color: red;" value="2">2</option>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0 €</td>
      <td>

        <select name="standard12" id="frm-step1-standard12">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```